# HTML5 Image Maps - Not working on iOS devices?

Tags: html

I have an image map defined as follows:

```
<div>
    <img class="portalImageNonMobile" src="/Images/PortalPageNonMobile.jpg" alt="" usemap="#map">
</div>

<map name="map">
    <area id="travellers" class="mapTag" shape="rect" coords="115, 90, 345, 175" alt="Travellers" href="http://www.xxxxxxxxxxx.com/Home/Index/?Redirect=false" />
    <area id="serviceProviders" class="mapTag" shape="rect" coords="700, 90, 915, 175" alt="Service Providers" href="http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/Home/Index/?Redirect=false" />
</map>
```

This seems to work fine while testing it in various browsers on Windows devices. However, when we tried testing this on an iPad, the maps were not working (nothing would happen when tapping in the mapped areas). I know that image maps are in the HTML5 spec, so I would think that all browsers on all devices would support them. But it seems not Chrome on an iPad. Any ideas how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that image maps do not work on iOS devices (and perhaps not Mac either). So, through some research, I found SVG would work on all devices. Here is solution using SVG:

```
<figure>
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1200 808" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
        <image width="1200" height="808" xlink:href="/Images/PortalPageNonMobile.jpg"></image>

        <a id="travellers" xlink:href="http://www.xxxxxxxxx.com/Home/Index/?Redirect=false">
            <rect x="115" y="90" fill="#fff" opacity="0" width="310" height="95" />
        </a>

        <a id="serviceProviders" xlink:href="http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/Home/Index/?Redirect=false">
            <rect x="700" y="90" fill="#fff" opacity="0" width="330" height="95" />
        </a>
    </svg>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SVG maps, they are supported in all modern browsers, works responsively and are as easy to use as image maps.

Answer (score 0):

Well, thank goodness we're losing functionality that has served the web since... what? 1992? ...in favor of... new stuff that does the exact same thing. Oy.